# Hibernate Null Pointer at AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator User Type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here's a fragment of my spring configuration for hibernate

```
<bean id="adminDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="username" value="username"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="adminDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan"  value = "mypackage.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.sql.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">SCHEMA</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">mypackage.SchemaResolver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"mypackage.MultitenantConnectionProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Here's my SchemaResolver class

```
public class SchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return "public"; //TODO: Implement service to identify tenant like: userService.getCurrentlyAuthUser().getTenantId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's my MultitenantConnectionProvider

```
public class MultitenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4368575201221677384L;

    private C3P0ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = null;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        Map lSettings = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings();

        connectionProvider = new C3P0ConnectionProvider();
        connectionProvider.injectServices(serviceRegistry);
        connectionProvider.configure(lSettings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
        }
        connectionProvider.closeConnection(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

upon running my app here's the exception I get

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:80)
            at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:61)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
            at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)

            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at 

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
2014-12-05 21:26:45.136:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
```

I am using hibernate 4.3.6 Final with Joda Time 2.4 , Spring Framework at 4.1.1.RELEASE, JDK version javac 1.8.0_20, and I am using Postgresql with PostgreSQL driver  9.3-1102-jdbc41

Comment: Can you tell us which version of spring and hibernate you are using?

Comment: Looks like "type" is null.  I'd guess that one of your entities isn't getting mapped properly.  Or maybe an Enum or subclass is missing somewhere?

Comment: @M2je Added information about the versions I am using. should I include the jadira user type versions as well?

Comment: I'm not sure but this might be useful [link](https://jadira.atlassian.net/browse/JDF-81). I think you may be using an older version you JDBC driver or something like that .
Can you Also tell us about the Database and JDK version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, using Hibernate 4.3.6 and Jadira usertype 4.0.0.GA.

My guess is that the library Jadira usertype 4.0.0.GA is not compatible with multi-tenancy mode of Hibernate.

My solution is to remove usertype dependency and obviously don't use it in the code.
For now you have to choose using hibernate multi-tenancy or using usertype.

For more details, usertype uses deprecaded API `ConnectionProvider getConnectionProvider()` which returns null on multi-tenancy mode because `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` is not an instance of `ConnectionProvider`. In multi-tenancy mode there is no service of type `ConnectionProvider`. Usertype should use a `JdbcConnectionAccess` instead.

I hope it'll be fixed in next versions.

Comment: The issue with multitenancy is addressed in Jadira 5.0.0.GA. Disclaimer: I maintain Jaira.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Chris Pheby, you can fix it by upgrading Jadira version to 5.0.0.GA

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression introduced in Usertype 3.2.0.GA. Downgrading to version 3.1.0.GA eliminates this exception.

Please see https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/issues/19 for a bug report.

Comment: Or, upgrading to 5.0.0.GA of Jadira fixes the issue with Hibernate 5.0. Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira.